# ->where() clauses seem to be case sensitive

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, where-clause, fluent

I have a query like so:

```
$profilesx->where('qZipCode', $location)->
                        orWhere('qCity', 'LIKE', '%'.$location.'%');
```

Where location is equal to `belgrade`, and the database column says `Belgrade`.

It seems to be case sensitive (using either = or LIKE) so if I search for `Belgrade` I get a result but if I search for `belgrade` I do not get any results.

How to make it case insensitive?

Comment: What's the column's collation? That defines the *default* comparison method...

Comment: Is the table/column collation `ci` or `cs`?

Comment: Try `orWhere('LOWER(qCity)', 'LIKE', '%'.strtolower($location).'%');` (You may need to do a `\DB:raw` instead)

Comment: @deceze Table's collation seems to be utf8_bin, does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The default character set and collation are latin1 and
>   latin1_swedish_ci, so nonbinary string comparisons are case
>   insensitive by default. This means that if you search with col_name
>   LIKE 'a%', you get all column values that start with A or a. To make
>   this search case sensitive, make sure that one of the operands has a
>   case sensitive or binary collation. For example, if you are comparing
>   a column and a string that both have the latin1 character set, you can
>   use the COLLATE operator to cause either operand to have the
>   latin1_general_cs or latin1_bin collation:

source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case-sensitivity.html

What's actually happened is that the case sensitivity has been switched off (which is not neccassarily a bad thing). The solution is given in the next section of that document. Try something like

```
orWhere('qCity', 'COLLATE latin1_general_cs LIKE', '%'.$location.'%');
```

If laravel doesn't like it you will have to use a raw query or change the collation setting for the column.

As a side note, try to avoid LIKE %something% queries if you can. Mysql cannot use an index for these sorts of queries and they generally tend to be slow on large tables because of it.

Comment: Table's collation seems to be utf8_bin, can it be altered in SQL so that it bec0mes ci?

Comment: I do not recommend it. You are likely to have quite a few city names there with non ascii characters. They will become garbled if you do. Better to do the collation for each query.

Comment: oh ok thanks. The COLLATE thingy does not work like in your example unfortunately.

Comment: I was worried that it might not. I am not very familiar with running these sorts of queries on laravel. Guess you will have to resort to a raw query.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually the collation settings for the database. You need to set it to a case insensitive collation type.

Read this link for more info:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case-sensitivity.html